# Does distinct function apply unique attribute to list in q kdb?

Tags: kdb

In output of asc function applied on a list, we can see that the output consists of sorted attribute.

```
q)asc 1 3 11 10 4
`s#1 3 4 10 11
```

But in the output of distinct function applied on a list, we cannot see unique attribute applied on the list.

```
q)distinct 1 3 11 10 4
1 3 11 10 4
```

But, the time taken to search an element in distinct list and unique list(list on which unique attribute is applied) is almost same.

```
q)n:1000000?1000000
q)d:distinct n
q)\t:100000 d[1021]
45
q)\t:100000 d[632265]
45
q)u:`u#d
q)\t:100000 u[1021]
44
q)\t:100000 u[632265]
48
```

So, is the distinct function applying unique attribute internally on the list and converting it to hash table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`distinct` does not apply unique attribute to list. You may see this with help of `attr` function

```
attr distinct 10?10
```

will return nothing `` ` ``, when

```
attr `u#distinct 10?10
```

returns `` `u ``

Also, I think the experiment may be wrong: `d[1021]` seems to be usual 0(1) time operation of getting element by index. If you use search instead, you'll see the difference (numbers on my PC):

```
q)\t:10000 d?770751
85
q)\t:10000 u?770751 
6
```

Comment: Agreed, your experiment is correct as in my case(question) getting the element from index in array is O[1]. 
Then then next question which occurs in my mind is why aren't q/k applying unique attribute on distinct function's output as the output of distinct functions will always be unique?

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I think that applying unique attribute creates an index, which usually takes more space than even original list. That's why this attribute is not set by distinct function, but should be set explicitly

Comment: Ahh got it. Applying unique attribute will require extra space as the list is being converted to hashtable for faster lookup. Hence to not use extra memory unique attribute might not have been applied in the output of distinct function. Thanks a lot!